# Orbeon Forms 2017 - how to make sections into tabbed pages

Tags: css, tabs, orbeon

How does one turn a collection of Sections on an Orbeon form into page tabs.  Its similar to the wizard view, except the tabs run across the top of the page and they don't assume a page workflow.

The intent would be to use Forms Builder to implement a UI in a web application, vs being a regular data collection capture form.

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, showing the "tabs" at the top of the page, rather the left side, isn't supported out-of-the-box, and this is tracked as [request for enhancement 3033](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3033).

As a side note, I have seen people do this, I imagine with CSS, but suspect it isn't just a matter of adding a few rules, and requires some work.